# Oracle SQL Conditional Select Query

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

I have this table below

```
uid    rid   time_type    date_time

a11    1     2            5/4/2013 00:32:00 (row1)
a43    1     1            5/4/2013 00:32:01 (row2)
a68    1     1            5/4/2013 00:32:02 (row3)
a98    1     2            5/4/2013 00:32:03 (row4)
a45    1     2            5/4/2013 00:32:04 (row5)
a94    1     1            5/4/2013 00:32:05 (row6)
a35    1     2            5/4/2013 00:32:07 (row7)
a33    1     2            5/4/2013 00:32:08 (row8)
```

Can I use a normal select query to extract the data such that it becomes

```
uid    rid   time_type    date_time

a43    1     1            5/4/2013 00:32:01 (row2)
a98    1     2            5/4/2013 00:32:03 (row4)
a94    1     1            5/4/2013 00:32:05 (row6)
a35    1     2            5/4/2013 00:32:07 (row7)
```

The date_time field is in asc order. logic is that time_type '1' needs to be paired with the next time_type '2' of the same rid. If time_type '1' or '2' appears in a group of 2 or more ordered by date_time, I will take the earlier one and ignore the rest.

Can this be done?

Comment: This is tagged mysql and Oracle.  Which are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
with src as (
  select tst.*,  
         case when time_type <> lag( time_type) over ( partition by rid order by date_time, time_type ) 
            then 1 else 0
         end take_me
  from tst
) 
select * from src where take_me = 1
order by rid, date_time;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5291c/1)